# Continuous input commands

Tags: java, console, user-input, java.util.scanner

My program will read user keyboard commands in the form of "`command` `parameter`" with a space in between. It keeps carrying out individual commands until the next command is "`exit`". Also, if the user messes up, the program should show an error but continue asking for commands (a feature I don't think I have completed)..

Is the following code a good way of implementing this? Could it handle the user simply pressing the enter key w/o a command, junk input, etc? If anything, I would love to know if there is a better idiomatic way implementing this.

```
String command = "";
String parameter = "";
Scanner dataIn = new Scanner(System.in);

while (!command.equals("exit")) {
    System.out.print(">> ");

    command = dataIn.next().trim();
    parameter = dataIn.next().trim();
    //should ^ these have error handling?

    if (command.equals("dothis")) {
        //do this w/ parameter..
    } else if (command.equals("dothat")) {
        //do that w/ parameter..
    } //else if... {}
      else {
        system.out.println("Command not valid.");
    }
}

System.out.println("Program exited by user.");
```

Note: I took this class without a single notion of what exception handling is, so any pointers in that area is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: A little note: you should always make a call to `dataIn.hasNext()` prior to calling `dataIn.next()` to make sure `next()` is a valid call. Typically the loop head is `while (dataIn.hasNext())` or `while (dataIn.hasNextLine())` when parsing input commands.

Comment: so `while (!command.equals("exit") && dataIn.hasNextLine())`?

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple way to implement an input loop:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

for (prompt(); sc.hasNextLine(); prompt()) {

    String line = sc.nextLine().replaceAll("\n", "");

    // return pressed
    if (line.length == 0) 
        continue;

    // split line into arguments
    String[] args = line.split(" ");    

    // process arguments
    if (args.length == 1) {
        if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("exit"))
            System.exit(0);
        if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("dosomething"))
            // do something
    } else if (args.length == 2) {
        // do stuff with parameters
    } 
}
```

Assuming `prompt()` prints out the prompt here.

Comment: would prompt() just be `System.out.println(">> ");`?

Comment: Almost. It would be `System.out.print(">> ");`

Comment: Right. Also why would args[] be length 1, not 2? shouldn't split return args[0] and args[1]?

Comment: See my update. `args` could be any length it was just to illustrate the first case.