# Java: How do I continuously scan for input?

Tags: java, oop, input, java.util.scanner

I am trying to write a program in Java that allows the user to modify an AddressBook. I have written the code that creates the AddressBook and functions that allow for it to be modified:

```
public class AddressBookEntry 
{
    private String name, phone, email;
    public AddressBookEntry(String name, String phone, String email)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getName() 
    {
        return name;
    }
    public String getPhone() 
    {
        return phone;
    }
    public String getEmail() 
    {
        return email;
    }
}
```

and

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AddressBook
{
    private ArrayList<AddressBookEntry> book = new ArrayList<AddressBookEntry>();
    public AddressBook(String bookname)
    {

    }
    public void addEntry(String name, String phone, String email)
    {
        book.add(new AddressBookEntry(name, phone, email));
    }
    public AddressBookEntry Search(String searchkey)
    {
        for (AddressBookEntry entry: book)
        {
            if (entry.getName() == searchkey)
                {
                    return entry;
                }
        }
    return null;
    }
    public void removeEntry(String searchkey)
    {
        AddressBookEntry removeentry = Search(searchkey);
        book.remove(removeentry);
    }
}
```

I am now trying to write another class that uses user input to execute the above functions. I need to continuously scan for the input.

I have tried using `Scanner` but can only get this to work when the program prompts for input, e.g. `"Type an entry to add: "`. What is the best way to go about solving this problem without having the program prompt for input?

Comment: Maybe this answers your question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396765/continuous-input-commands

Comment: `I have tried using Scanner but can only get this to work when the program prompts for input, e.g.` then you've done it wrong and since you haven't included that code, we can't help you to fix that. You can update your question, if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use this putting in the `while` your exit condition:

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

while (...) {
    System.out.print("Type an entry to add: ");
    String input = bufferedReader.readLine();
    ...
}
```

Now you have in the `input` the string entered by the user.

Example:

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

while (true) {
    System.out.print("Type an entry to add: ");
    String input = bufferedReader.readLine();
    if (input.equals("exit"))
        break;
    ...
}
```

This program exit when the user type `"exit"`.